Spring Boot (3.5.0) - Rest Controller - 400 with HTML response body
I am encountering a problem that spring boot restful service returns 400(badRequest) with html response body when the request uri path variable is blank for example:
URI path:  ../v1/users/{id}/job where id is blank and so the request path will be ../v1/users//job.
I tried following options

adding exception handler for 'NoHandlerFoundException' at @ControllerAdvice class
added throw-exception-in-no-handler-found in the application config
Extended ErrorController with request mapping "/error"
implements RequestRejectedHandler
No luck.

How to deal with this kind of an exception to write custom json in the response.
Sample Code:
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v1")
@Validated
public class SampleController {@GetMapping(value = 
"/users/{id}/jobs")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(
        @RequestHeader(value = "requestId") String requestId,
        @PathVariable("id") @NotNull String userId) {
    String formattedMessage = "GET jobs [%s 
       %s]".formatted(requestId,userId);
    System.out.print(formattedMessage);
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
   }

}
REQUEST:
curl http://localhost:8080/v1/users//jobs -H 'requestId: b4c0-a6ddc4807cf1'
RESPONSE:
<!doctype html>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Requestbody {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request

Can you provide a little stacktrace when 400 occur?

... and maybe even some parts of your Controller's code?

@NguyenManhCuong,
It can't see any traces/root cause in the application logs other than the following response body


HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request



HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request


@MarioMateaș kindly check the sample controller code

HTTP 400 is bad request not a NOT FOUND (404). So trying to use solutions for the 404 for a 400 case is obviously not going work. The @PathVariable is required, it is missing and as such it will give a 400.

@M.Deinum Thanks for your reply. Yes it 400, but I can't handle this exception to response with nice json formatted message or with no body instead HTML response. It look so wired responding 400 with html response body. Is there anyway to handle this 400. Thanks

@dina75, there are 2 types of handling exception, one is handling each exception, ex NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException, ... to some custom response. Another is handling by status code, may your goal is the second ?

Thanks for your reply @NguyenManhCuong, somehow i wanted to interrupt unknown situation for 400 (badRequest) when path variable is blank which in turn produces double slash in the middle of the URL.  It can be either by status code or that unknown exception.

Why should it not respond with a HTML page. Your page is marked as an @Controller which is used to render pages. So unless you slap an @ResponseBody on the method or use @RestController instead of @Controller it will return HTML.

@M.Deinum, Thanks for the reply. I am using RESTful service (API) and so id doesn't need to resolve any view (HTML). All I need to respond with Json body. I tried with annotation RestController, but still no luck.

Handling by Exception Class
You should have a entity named BaseResponseError:
public class BaseResponseError {
    int error = 0;
    Object message; // <-- Contains your message when err occur

    public static BaseResponseError error(Object message) {
        return new BaseResponseError(1, message);
    }
}

The handler exception class:
@RestControllerAdvice // <-- Define the class contains some @ExceptionHandler
public class CustomExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) 
    // If this exception  (NohandlerFoundException) occur, 400 will responded.

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    // If the exception is instance of NoHandlerFoundException, Spring will execute this method.

    public BaseResponse handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex) {
        return BaseResponseError.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

Your Api will return something like this:
{
    "error":1,
    "message":"Hellllllllllo?  What are you doing here"
}

